# Multiple image upload in one table and one column

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo

I am struggling to make this work, i have no idea how to code it. I want to upload 1 to max 5 images from one input field (don't need to be one input field) to db table. To avoid any confusion, i only want to store image name in table, but image to folder. Single image upload is working fine but i need image upload to max 5 images.

**here is my code for now:**

```
        $pdo = connect();
    if(isset($_POST['insertp'])) {

    $InputTitle         = $_POST['InputTitle'];
    $InputDescription   = $_POST['InputDescription'];
    $InputCategory      = $_POST['InputCategory'];

    if(isset($_FILES['InputImage'])){
      $name_array = $_FILES['InputImage']['name'];
      $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['InputImage']['tmp_name'];
      $type_array = $_FILES['InputImage']['type'];
      $size_array = $_FILES['InputImage']['size'];
      $error_array = $_FILES['InputImage']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "../assets/images/".$name_array[$i])){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
            }
        }
    }

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO product(title,description,id_category,image) 
                          VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4)");
    $sql->execute(array(':field1' => $InputTitle,
                        ':field2' => $InputDescription,
                        ':field3' => $InputCategory,
                        ':field4' => $name_array));
    $affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows > 0) {
    header( "refresh:0" );
    die();
    }
}
```

**This is my table in witch i want to store data.** is it possible to store more than one image name i one column(image)?

id | title | description | id_category | image

**and this is my input field:**

```
<div class="form-group"> <!-- IMAGE -->
            <label for="image">Image upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="InputImage[]" id="InputImage" value="">
            <input type="file" name="InputImage[]" id="InputImage" value="">
            <input type="file" name="InputImage[]" id="InputImage" value="">
            <input type="file" name="InputImage[]" id="InputImage" value="">
            <input type="file" name="InputImage[]" id="InputImage" value="">
            <p class="help-block">Select image.</p>
          </div>
```

I know that there is a lot of similar questions here, but i don't know how to implement them in my code, so if you can help me i will appreciate it!

Comment: First: you never bother checking if the upload succeeded. That is very BAD programming practice. SEcond, since you're using the `[]` naming hack, you'll have to `foreach($_FILES['InputImage']['name'] as $key => $name)`, then access the various $_FILES parameters using `$key` to get your sub-array of images. e.g. `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what the multi-file upload structure is (hint: it's insanely stupid)

Comment: I know that it isn't best practice but for now it will work, i am learning step by step. Can you help me implement that what you sad to my code. And how will it save image name's to table...in one column